# Open web frameworks for making searchable multilingual dictionaries

Tags: web, language, dictionary

Is there any open-source web framework for making searchable multilingual dictionaries, that have good support for making plugins or API to automate making new entries?

Some background: In my studies, I often have to write texts in my mother language, whereas most of the research papers are published in English. As the research field is very specific and fairly new (connecting machine learning, cognitive science and robot control), there are often no translations in traditional dictionaries. It's a very tedious procedure to search in different repositories of previous theses to check if someone already used the same terminology and translated it in the bilingual abstracts. Often that procedure ends in scrolling through Wikipedia articles in both languages to match the terminology, just to find that multiple translations exist. 
Therefore, I would like to build a collection of translations I use and eventually write a plugin that automates comparing the thesis abstracts in multiple languages.

I am having something like [this](https://isjfr.zrc-sazu.si/sl/terminologisce/slovarji/avtomatika/iskalnik?ustreznik=feedforward%20%20matrix&jezik=ang#v) or [this](https://www.termania.net/iskanje?ld=20&query=error&SearchIn=All) in mind.

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_memory software?

Comment: No, I want something with a searchable web interface and a possibility to add new entries, so that my colleagues could eventually also expand the collection.

Comment: Most translation memory platforms allow colleagues to use the same translation memory database, everyone being able to add new entries.